# Joomla Empty Sessions and Cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, joomla

I am having issues with sessions/cookies while using Joomla! Version: Joomla! 1.5.9 Production/Stable [ Vatani ] 9-January-2009 23:00 GMT.

I am trying to save data into a session and access it on the next page, i have tried:

1) Using joomlas sessions ($session->set('var', 'data')) - This is my preferred method

2) Using normal PHP sessions ($_SESSION['Var'] = 'data') - This works fine until i initialize the joomla mainframe

3) Using PHP Cookies (setcookie('var', 'data', time()+3600,'/');) - Again this works until i initialize joomla.

Here is the code i am trying to use:

Page 1:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();

$thedata = array();
$i = 0;
if($resultscount > 0) // $resultscount = mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1097 in my script
{
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                $thedata[$i]['id'] = $row['user_id'];
                ...LOTS more additions to $thedata, 1000+ rows containing 28 variables each.
$i++;
}
$session->set('thedata',$thedata);
```

Page 2:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../..' ));
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();

$session = JFactory::getSession();
print_r($session->get('thedata'));
```

The session is always empty. I have noticed if the session only contains a small amount of data (1 or 2 rows) it works, but when i try to save a large number of results into the session it breaks and the session is empty on the next page.

The same thing happens with cookie, few results = works fine, lots of results = cookie empty.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: before I rant, please upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26, which is the latest version of the 1.5 series

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply however I cannot upgrade as I am writing a bolt on for someone's system and do not have their permission to upgrade their existing joomla platform.

Comment: Do you have a valid session handler in configuration.php?

Comment: var $session_handler = 'database'; so yes the session handler is correct

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, storing more than 30000 variables in a two-dimensional array in the session, you get an overflow that corrupts your data, so they get lost. You gain nothing by duplicating the database in the session storage (which is limited in space).

It is more appropriate to re-query the data. Also, use the Joomla! API instead of directly using mysql functions.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT ...");
$thedata = $db->loadObjectList('id');
```

is all you need (double indexing with `$i` does not serve any purpose).